# Why isn't my custom management command recognised?

Tags: python, django

I have made a custom management command "`send_daily_report`". It just aggregates a few usage statistics, and sends an email. My intent is for it to be called by cron each day.

The command looks like this (simplified example):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from my_app.models import Widget
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    commands = ['send_daily_report',]
    help = 'Daily activity report'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        context = {}
        context['new_widgets'] = Widgets.objects\
            .filter(date_created__gt=(datetime.now() - timedelta(1)) )\
            .count()
        text_body = render_to_string('daily_activity_report.txt', context)
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject="Daily report",
            body=text_body,
            from_email='noreply@example.com',
            to=[u.email for u in User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)]
        )
        email.send(fail_silently=True)
```

This is in `/my_project/management/commands/send_daily_report.py` as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). I have an `__init__.py` in each directory, and a `__pycache__` with pyc files indicating that the file compiles. I'm using Python 3, Django 1.11. `manage.py check` reports no errors.

Running `manage.py send_daily_report` gives me:

> Unknown command: 'send_daily_report'.

In the shell, I can do:

```
>>> from my_project.management.commands.send_daily_report import Command
```

What's causing the management command not to be recognised?

Comment: Is `my_project` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: you need move the `management` to one of yours app

Comment: That worked, but I've split the project into several apps, and it doesn't really make conceptual sense because the command reports on all the apps. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add a `management` app for this and like utilities.

Comment: @Escher don't worry about, just find something like `common_app` and create such commands in it